# Django rest framework question: Using TestCase I'm not understanding using fixtures

Tags: django-rest-framework, pytest, fixtures

I'm confused about factories.

```
@pytest.fixture
def a_api_request_factory():
    return APIRequestFactory()

class TestUserProfileDetailView(TestCase):

    def test_create_userprofile(self, up=a_user_profile, rf=a_api_request_factory):
        """creates an APIRequest and uses an instance of UserProfile from a_user_profile to test a view user_detail_view"""

        request  = rf().get('/api/userprofile/') # the problem line
        request.user = up.user
        response = userprofile_detail_view(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.data['user'], up.user.username)
```

if I take out the parens from rf().get.... then I get

> "function doesn't have a get attribute".

If I call it directly then it gives me:

> "Fixture "a_api_request_factory" called directly. Fixtures are not
> meant to be called directly, but are created automatically when test
> functions request them as parameters. See
> https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html for more information
> about fixtures, and
> https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/deprecations.html#calling-fixtures-directly
> about how to update your code."

I do believe I've hit every combination of with or without parens in all relevant locations.  Where do the parens go for fixtures?

Or better yet is there a pattern to avoid this type of confusion completely?

Comment: A fixture parameter has to be passed as a parameter, not as a default argument, e.g. `def test_create_userprofile(self, a_user_profile, a_api_request_factory)`.

Comment: If I do that I get "TypeError: test_create_userprofile() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a_user_profile' and 'a_api_request_factory'"

Comment: Ah, I see you are using unittest - mixing unittest and pytest is not the best idea. Is there a reason why you are deriving from `TestCase`?

Comment: I took out inheriting from "TestCase" and still no luck.  Error in the same spot.  I ripped out the fixture decorator, no luck (error: something along the lines of can't do database access)

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what exactly you are just trying?

Comment: I can't mix factories and fixtures.  I've taken out all the fixtures.  I'm still getting database errors "RuntimeError: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.".   The core problem seems to be I can't make a UserProfileFactory based on another UserFactory.   I'll post a different question and put it in the comments here.

Comment: I think this is a reduced problem set can be found here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69733775/django-factory-using-a-factory-gives-database-access-not-allowed