# django factory using a factory gives "Database access not allowed"

Tags: django, factories

I want to create a user_profile from a factory called UserProfileFactory which uses a User object from UserFactory.

the error is: RuntimeError: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.

here are the relivant classes.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from factory import Faker, post_generation
from factory.django import DjangoModelFactory

class UserFactory(DjangoModelFactory):

    username = Faker("user_name")
    email = Faker("email")
    name = Faker("name")

    @post_generation
    def password(self, create: bool, extracted: Sequence[Any], **kwargs):
        password = (
            extracted
            if extracted
            else Faker(
                "password",
                length=42,
                special_chars=True,
                digits=True,
                upper_case=True,
                lower_case=True,
            ).evaluate(None, None, extra={"locale": None})
        )
        self.set_password(password)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        django_get_or_create = ["username"]



class UserProfileFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    user = UserFactory.create()  #### the problem line ###
    country = Faker("country") # which laws apply
    birth_date = Faker("date_of_birth") # in the US you can't collect data from <13yo's

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
```

and in the tests/test.py

```
class TestUserProfileDetailView():
    def test_create_userprofile(self):
        """creates an APIRequest and uses an instance of UserProfile to test a view user_detail_view"""

        factory = APIRequestFactory()
        request = factory.get('/api/userprofile/')
        request.user = UserProfileFactory.create()  # problem starts here #
        response = user_detail_view(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#pytest-mark-django-db-request-database-access

Comment: Yes I saw this.  I don't want to save it to a database.  It's a test.  I've just come off of trying to get fixtures to work.  I stripped them out because it's a nightmare.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69718134/django-rest-framework-question-using-testcase-im-not-understanding-using-fixtu

Comment: Also I've tried inheriting TestUserProfileDetailView with and without django.test.TestCase which comes up the same way each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I know this is an old one, but in case someone else finds this question later)

I think what you want is the `build` method. The `create` method saves the instance in the database (which you said you *don't* want) but the `build` method doesn't.

[Here's an explanation in the factory-boy docs of `build` and `create`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#using-factories).